# How to ignore several directories in Git

Tags: git

I'm going to be uploading several files to a community Git project, and I am only supposed to upload certain files without permission, then ask for permission to upload all the rest should I need to change them. So, I would like Git to just ignore all the directories I don't have permission to freely change, so I can freely upload what I want, and then should the need arise, upload the directories I've changed that I don't have permission to.

What would be the best way about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those directories (you don't have permission to change directly) are already versioned, I wouldn't recommend a `.gitignore` solution as:

- you risk to add, commit and push that `.gitignore` (which the remote repo doesn't want to change)
- it wouldn't work anyway, without removing those folders from the index (`git rm -r --cached /folders/you/dont/have/permission`), which in turn risk to be committed and push (the remote repo wants those folders!)

It is best to apply a *local* solution (which doesn't risk to be pushed by mistake).

Before adding anything, do (for the folder you don't have permission) a:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- /folder
```

See "[using git skip-worktree to disable file updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672192/6309)".
Your `git status`, `git add` and `git commit` should ignore that already versioned folder, even if you have modified/added files in it.

You can reverse that local change with a:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- /folder
```

Comment: When I was required to make an update to it the directory I don't usually have permission to access, and I had been given permission, how would I go about unblocking the directory? I really like your answer, I would just like to know ahead of time.

Comment: @josh you can simply reverse the update-index with a `git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- /folder`. From there, you changes in that folder will again be visible, added and committed.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very informative, and helped me alot.